# Parse String with delimiter symbol into Array

Tags: java, arrays, string, parsing, delimiter

I have a file containing lines of this type:

"Andorra la Vella|ad|Andorra la Vella|20430|42.51|1.51"

I basically just want to have a String Array containing the entries between the | delimiter:

["Andorra la Vella", "ad", "Andorra la Vella", "20430", "42.51", "1.51"]

Can this be done with regular expressions?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Yes use String.split() for each line as you read it from the file.

```
line.split("\\|");
```

Comment: But @pangea can you explain why we need to add that "\\"?

Comment: @chiranjeevibmse You probably found out already: The `|` needs to be escaped because split expects a regex value, not a string, and `|` is a reserved character in regex. http://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html

Answer (score 22):

An alternative is to use `String.split(...)`

```
String s="Hi farshad zeinali/ how are you?/i have a question!/can you help me?";
String[] ss=s.split("/");
for(int i=0;i<ss.length;i++)
{
    System.out.println(ss[i]);
}
```